# Mageto2 How to get created user id in API

Tags: magento2, customer, api, user

I am creating a user by API. After creation:

- How to get that user id?
- How to set this user into de-active stage?

My code:

```
$registrationdata = [
        'customer' => [
            "email" => "sampleuser@example.com",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1
        ],
        "password" => "Demo1234"
    ];
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($registrationdata));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

The customer id is already from the result, for example:

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "group_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2017-08-04 03:44:56",
  "updated_at": "2017-08-04 03:44:56",
  "created_in": "Default Store View",
  "email": "sampleuser@example.com",
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "store_id": 1,
  "website_id": 1,
  "addresses": [],
  "disable_auto_group_change": 0
}
```

You should print the result. Add these lines to your code:

```
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

> How to set this user into de-active stage.

There is a config in Admin to enable the email confirmation: **STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Require Emails Confirmation > Yes**

Comment: Thank You...ButI am creating these users by API, so i want to create these users by default in to deactive-stage programmatically?

Comment: Okay! Let me check again.